# Processing all files in a directory- different types

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to write a code right now to run every file in a directory with a function I just made. The thing is, the files in the directory will be of three types (.wav, .txt, and, the output of the program, .TextGrid), and will need to be passed in as arguments in the code. So, for example, the specific .wav file must go with it's specific .txt file, to make a specifically names .TextGrid file. These files are arguments that I'm passing through a subprocess that actually runs another program, the Forced Aligner from Penn State. Let me know if you are confused about any the code or its function.

Also I'm new to coding so I know my code is probably not the most efficient thing as it is. I felt that using input instead of argv would be easier for this instance, mostly because I don't know how to specify that there could be a different amount of arguments each time (I'm trying to make this code more universal, but for my purposes, there will only be 1 program and 3 arguments each time.

```
import subprocess
import sys

def run_file(num_args):
    prog = input('Enter the program directory: ')
    args = input('Enter the arguments\' directories separated by a space: ').split(' ', len(num_args)-1)
    subprocess.call([prog, args])

def main():
    run_file(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: so basically do you want to take in two file with .wav and .txt extensions and create a third .TextGrid naming it respective to the names of the first two files?

Comment: @JayT. sort of, I will be processing the files with the forced aligner, which is another Python program that matched audio to a script and produce a file (the text grid) that is readable by the program praat. it's for a linguistics lab.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) to get a list of all files with a certain suffix, for example all .txt files. Then you can check if a matching .wav file is present and pass then to the aligner.

```
import glob
import subprocess
import os

def main():
    # specify program
    prog = input('Enter the program directory: ')
    # no program is given, use a default program
    if not prog:
        prog = "./align.py"

    # compile a list of all .txt files in the current directory
    # using glob wildcards
    all_txt_files = glob.glob("*.txt")

    for txt_file in all_txt_files:
        # get the basename of the txt file, triming off the extension
        filename, ext = os.path.splitext(txt_file)
        # compile filenames for wav and textgrid file
        wav_file = filename + ".wav"
        grid_file = filename + ".TextGrid"
        # make sure the wav file exists
        if os.path.exists(wav_file):
            # call the program
            args = [txt_file, wav_file, grid_file]
            subprocess.Popen([prog] + args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am not 100% sure if this is what you were up to. If you would like to allow different parameters, consider making the constant strings I used a user input or a command line argument. I have not tested this, but it might look somewhat like this:

```
    input_suffixes = input('Enter input suffixes\' separated by spaces').split(" ")
    if not input_suffixes:
        input_suffixes = ".txt .wav"

    output_suffixes = input('Enter output suffixes\' separated by spaces').split(" ")
    if not output_suffixes:
        output_suffixes = ".TextGrid"

    first_suffix, *input_suffixes = input_suffixes    
    all_files = glob.glob("*"+first_suffix)

    for in_file in all_txt_files:
        filename, ext = os.path.splitext(txt_file)
        in_files = [filename+suffix for suffix in input_suffixes]
        out_files = [filename+suffix for suffix in output_suffixes]

        args = [in_file] + in_files + out_files
        subprocess.Popen([prog] + args)
```

#### Sidenote

If you are using a linux machine it might be simpler (or at least shorter) to write a bash script to solve this:

```
for f in *.txt; do
  python align.py $f `basename $f .txt`.wav `basename $f .txt`.TextGrid;
done
```

This iterates through all .txt files, passes the filename on to align.py. The filenames for the other files are created using the basename command `basename $f .txt` which trims off a suffix from the file. Then the .wav and .TextGrid suffix are added.

I hope this helps, even though the lab, most certainly, is long over.